# React Native - "Roulette" effect on Array shifting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Summary:**
I'm trying to achieve a "roulette" effect on my array. 
Assuming I have an array of 5 strings with a function that shifts the value of `N` index to `N + 1` with the last index going back to 0.

These strings are presented in a stacked manner with first string on top and last string at the bottom.

[image: stacks]

**Expected:**
Clicking the `Test` button Animate the stacked string in a roulette effect

**What have I tried:**
Below is the `Test` button function that I created which randomizes the number of shift times before shifting the value of strings to the next index.

```
test = async () => {

    const shiftTimes = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);

    for (let i = 0; i < shiftTimes; i ++ ) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const myList = this.state.myList;

            const temp = myList[myList.length - 1];
            for (let j = myList.length - 1; j > 0; j --) {
                myList[j] = myList[j-1];
            }
            myList[0] = temp

            this.setState({
                myList: myList
            });
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

**Current effect:**
While the function does the job of what a roulette should, it lacks the animation even with the `setTimeout`. It does "animate" on the browser although laggy but on native devices, it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "animating" exactly? Do you want the texts to visibly move up and change size and opacity? or do you want them to "jump" continuously `100ms` apart? I'm asking, because it looks like, with your current code, the texts will change only once and be set to the final arrangement. Is that what it does?

Comment: Right, I want to make them seem to like it's rotating. Testing the code on the browser, it happens visually although laggy. On native device, as you said, the text only changes once after the final arrangement.

Comment: Are you (or have you tried) using the `Animated` library? The entire implementation for achieving what you're trying to achieve would probably be too big to write here as an answer. I can point you in the right direction if you'd like. I'm asking, because it might take some time for you to do this, and I don't know what kind of time commitment you're willing to put in trying to resolve this issue. Your question sounds like you're looking for an easy fix, expecting that native will automatically animate the changes, but it won't.